# Change the same variable to a new string if

Tags: php

I have multiple options for a user to select a rate. If the user selects no charge, the value is going to be 0.00. When the user submits the form, i want it to display "No Charge" on the email instead of 0.00

Why isnt this working?

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio11" class="radio" value="0.00" />
            <span class="lbl">No Charge</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="radiochoice" id="radio7" class="radio" value="185.00"  />
            <span class="lbl">Networking: $185.00</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
$radiochoice = $_POST['radiochoice'];   

$nochargevalue = 0.00;
if ($radiochoice == $nochargevalue) {          
    $radiochoice = "No Charge";
} else {

}
```

The Email

```
<th style="background:#ebebeb;border-color: #ebebeb;">Rate</label></th>
<td>' . $_POST['radiochoice'] .' </td>
```

Fix thanks to @Stevish - im sadden that i missed this:

```
<th style="background:#ebebeb;border-color: #ebebeb;">Rate</label></th>
<td>' . $radiochoice .' </td>
```

Comment: you ignored my suggestions on how to code things properly last time, so no help from me

Comment: You're using $_POST in the email instead of $radiochoice.

Comment: doh! thank you. How is it duplicate when its a completely different question?